# Database slows down at millions of rows, how to optimize schema and queries?

Tags: mysql, performance, innodb, schema, scalability, query-performance

I am building a database to store Ethereum Transactions that are connected to specific addresses.  Once the database table `eth_addresses_tx` starts hitting 3 million + rows, things start slowing down a lot and CPU starts hitting 100%.  Storage is fine, 1 million rows is about 300mb.  Before spending more money on a server, I would like to see if there is any ways to improve the schema and queries.  The project will have 15-20 million rows to start and may have a lot more in the near future.  There will be 200-500 unique addresses and those addresses may contain a small amount of rows (1,000) up to a larger amount (3 million).  I could use some advice.  Thank you.

**Update:** 1 more index has been added to `datetimeTx` on the transactions table `eth_address_tx` which fixed performance on almost all the queries besides the last 2 on this post.

Table purposes:

`eth_addresses` - It stores addresses and meta data about the address being tracked.

`eth_addresses_stats` - It stores statistics queried from the transactions table (eth_addresses_tx) such as how many transactions in certain periods etc.  A programming script is queried on a cron job

`eth_addresses_tx` - **TX is short for transaction** in the queries and schema. This table stores data from blockchain transactions attached to certain addresses.  The `value` column contains ETH amount for that transaction.  There is 1 index from_tx.

**MYSQL SCHEMA**

```
CREATE DATABASE addresses CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

USE addresses;

CREATE TABLE `eth_addresses` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
    `name` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL ,
    `website` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
    `address` VARCHAR(1024) NOT NULL COMMENT 'ETH addresses' ,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`), UNIQUE `unique` (`website`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `eth_addresses_stats` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `balance` decimal(16,6) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `tx_1h` int(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'transactions',
    `tx_24h` int(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'transactions',
    `tx_7d` int(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'transactions',
    `tx_all` int(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'transactions',
    `volume_1h` decimal(14,6) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `volume_24h` decimal(14,6) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `volume_7d` decimal(14,6) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `volume_all` decimal(14,6) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `users_1h` int(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `users_24h` int(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `users_7d` int(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `users_all` int(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `last_scraped` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES eth_addresses (id),
    UNIQUE (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE `eth_addresses_tx` (
    `hash` varchar(66) NOT NULL,
    `address_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `blockNumber` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `datetimeTx` datetime NOT NULL,
    `from_tx` varchar(42) NOT NULL,
    `to_tx` varchar(42) NOT NULL,
    `value` decimal(14,6) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (address_id) REFERENCES eth_addresses (id),
    PRIMARY KEY (`hash`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Transactions';
ALTER TABLE `eth_addresses_tx` ADD INDEX `from_tx` (`from_tx`);
```

**Slow Queries**

The queries below are ran periodically and the results are stored in a caching table.

These queries are gathering total stats from the transactions table `eth_addresses_tx` to be sent to `eth_addresses_stats`.  I was unsure how to combine them into 1 query so I wrote 4 queries.

**UPDATE** The 4 queries below are very fast with an index on datetimeTx.  Addresses with million + rows are now taking 0.14 seconds

```
SELECT IFNULL(SUM(value), 0) AS volume_1h,
       count(*) AS tx_1h,
       COUNT(DISTINCT from_tx) AS users_1h
FROM `eth_addresses_tx`
WHERE datetimeTx >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
  AND address_id = $address_id;


-- This query is slow on popular addresses with 1M+ rows
-- 1 row in set (32.30 sec) without explain
+----+-------------+-------------+------------+------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+---------+----------+------------------------+
| id | select_type | table            | partitions | type | possible_keys    | key        | key_len | ref   | rows    | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------------+------------+------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+---------+----------+------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | eth_addresses_tx | NULL       | ref  | address_id       | address_id | 4       | const | 1440328 |    33.33 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------------+------------+------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+---------+----------+------------------------+


SELECT IFNULL(SUM(value), 0) AS volume_24h,
       count(*) AS tx_24h, COUNT(DISTINCT from_tx) AS users_24h
FROM `eth_addresses_tx`
WHERE datetimeTx >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 24 HOUR)
  AND address_id = $address_id;

SELECT IFNULL(SUM(value), 0) AS volume_7d,
       count(*) AS tx_7d, COUNT(DISTINCT from_tx) AS users_7d
FROM `eth_addresses_tx`
WHERE datetimeTx >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 7 DAY)
  AND address_id = $address_id;

SELECT IFNULL(SUM(value), 0) AS volume_all,
       count(*) AS tx_all,
       COUNT(DISTINCT from_tx) AS users_all
FROM `eth_addresses_tx`
WHERE address_id = $address_id;
```

These queries are to get recent transactions from `eth_addresses_tx` with a few different where clauses:  Ordering by datetime is very slow, without ordering the query is very fast.

**UPDATE** The following 3 queries below are now very fast with an index on datetimeTx. 10 rows in set (0.00 sec)

```
SELECT  blockNumber, datetimeTx, address_id, from_tx, to_tx,
    value
     FROM  eth_addresses_tx
    WHERE  from_tx = $from_tx
    ORDER BY  datetimeTx DESC
    LIMIT  $limit;
SELECT  blockNumber, datetimeTx, address_id, from_tx, to_tx,
    value
     FROM  eth_addresses_tx
    WHERE  address_id = $address_id
    ORDER BY  datetimeTx DESC
    LIMIT  $limit;
SELECT  blockNumber, datetimeTx, address_id, from_tx, to_tx,
    value
     FROM  eth_addresses_tx
    ORDER BY  datetimeTx DESC
    LIMIT  $limit;
```

and

```
-- This query without explain = 10 rows in set (1.20 sec) 
-- This one is faster then the ones below
EXPLAIN SELECT  blockNumber, datetimeTx, address_id, from_tx, to_tx,
    value
     FROM  eth_addresses_tx
    WHERE  from_tx = $from_tx
    ORDER BY  datetimeTx DESC
    LIMIT  10;
+----+-------------+-------------+------------+------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+-------+----------+---------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table            | partitions | type | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref   | rows  | filtered | Extra                                 |
+----+-------------+-------------+------------+------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+-------+----------+---------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | eth_addresses_tx | NULL       | ref  | from_tx       | from_tx | 128     | const | 51680 |   100.00 | Using index condition; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+-------------+------------+------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+-------+----------+---------------------------------------+

-- This query without explain = 10 rows in set (31.51 sec)   
-- Address ids with a small amount of transactions query fast however address with large amounts of rows query very slow
EXPLAIN     SELECT  blockNumber, datetimeTx, address_id, from_tx, to_tx,
    value
     FROM  eth_addresses_tx
    WHERE  address_id = $address_id
    ORDER BY  datetimeTx DESC
    LIMIT  10;
+----+-------------+-------------+------------+------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+---------+----------+---------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table            | partitions | type | possible_keys | key        | key_len | ref   | rows    | filtered | Extra                                 |
+----+-------------+-------------+------------+------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+---------+----------+---------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | eth_addresses_tx | NULL       | ref  | address_id    | address_id | 4       | const | 1440242 |   100.00 | Using index condition; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+-------------+------------+------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+---------+----------+---------------------------------------+

-- This query without explain = 10 rows in set (9.93 sec)
EXPLAIN SELECT blockNumber, datetimeTx, address_id, from_tx, to_tx, value FROM eth_addresses_tx ORDER BY datetimeTx DESC LIMIT 10;
+----+-------------+-------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+----------+---------------------+
| id | select_type | table            | partitions | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows    | filtered | Extra          |
+----+-------------+-------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+----------+---------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | eth_addresses_tx | NULL       | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 2880430 |   100.00 | Using filesort |
+----+-------------+-------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+----------+---------------------+
```

These queries are to plot transaction data to a chart to track the volume.
**UPDATE** The following 3 queries below are now very fast with an index on datetimeTx.  73 rows in set (0.02 sec)

```
SELECT value FROM eth_addresses_tx WHERE address_id = $address_id AND value > 0 AND datetimeTx >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 HOUR);


-- This query is slow on popular addresses with 1M+ rows
-- 88 rows in set (31.81 sec) without explain
+----+-------------+-------------+------------+------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+---------+----------+-----------------------+
| id | select_type | table            | partitions | type | possible_keys    | key       | key_len | ref   | rows    | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------------+------------+------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+---------+----------+-----------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | eth_addresses_tx | NULL       | ref  | address_id       | address_id| 4       | const | 1440342 |    11.11 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------------+------------+------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+---------+----------+-----------------------+

SELECT value FROM eth_addresses_tx WHERE address_id = $address_id AND value > 0 AND datetimeTx >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 24 HOUR);
SELECT value FROM eth_addresses_tx WHERE address_id = $address_id AND value > 0 AND datetimeTx >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 7 DAY);
```

These queries are to figure out who is interacting with those addresses the most

```
SELECT d.name, count(d.id) AS total
        FROM `eth_addresses_tx` as tx
        LEFT JOIN eth_addresses AS d ON d.id = tx.address_id
        WHERE tx.from_tx = :address group by d.name

-- This query is not bad, pretty fast on smaller amounts
-- 1 row in set (1.06 sec) without explain
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+-------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref   | rows  | filtered | Extra                                              |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+-------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | tx    | NULL       | ref  | from_tx       | from_tx | 128     | const | 51680 |   100.00 | Using temporary; Using filesort                    |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | d     | NULL       | ALL  | PRIMARY       | NULL    | NULL    | NULL  |     5 |   100.00 | Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop) |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+-------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+


-----------------------------------------------------


SELECT from_tx, count(*) AS total_tx, SUM(value) as total_volume, count(DISTINCT address_id) as total_interacted
        FROM `eth_addresses_tx`
        GROUP BY from_tx
        ORDER BY total_tx DESC, from_tx DESC
        LIMIT 100;


-- This query is very bad
-- 100 rows in set (2 min 26.45 sec) without explain
-- sorting with any of the 3 items selected is slow
+----+-------------+-------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+---------+----------+--------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table            | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows    | filtered | Extra                           |
+----+-------------+-------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+---------+----------+--------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | eth_addresses_tx | NULL       | index | from_tx       | from_tx | 128     | NULL | 2880587 |   100.00 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+-------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+---------+----------+--------------------------------------+
```

Comment: I'd have a eth_addresses_stats table with only the 1h columns, and scrape_time iso. last_scraped.  I'd "scrape" every hour, selecting the records for the last hour from eth_addresses_tx , and inserting into eth_addresses_stats.  If I need 24h, 7d, I'd select that span from eth_addresses_stats and sum.

Comment: Thank you.  What do you mean by iso?  I need to query the data very often , every few minutes so I am unsure how I could do that and calculate proper sums for 24h and 7d.  If I took that approach, I am unsure how I would get previous history?  How do I ensure I don't miss data that way if the code takes a few minutes longer to run 1 time since it has to go through a few hundred addresses?

Comment: What does the [`Explain`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain.html) deliver for your statements? Please [edit](https://dba.stackexchange.com/posts/206475/edit) them in to your question.

Comment: iso = in stead of.  24h = select sum(1h) where scrape_time >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 24 HOUR).  To ensure you don't miss data while scraping: select where datetimeTx between ...

Comment: You need at least an index on datetimeTx on the eth_addresses_tx table.

Comment: No indices? https://use-the-index-luke.com/. Also- you lack server specs. You may well run on a joke of a server too small to handle this.

Comment: @JonathanFite  Just tested 1 query.  Went from 88 rows in set (31.81 sec)  > 81 rows in set (0.01 sec) , Wow!!!

Comment: There is an index on **from_tx** @TomTom and I just added an index to datetimeTx thanks to Jonathan's suggestion which has made a big difference.  Server is $10 Digital Ocean Droplet.  Will upgrade to something bigger, just trying to optimize for now.

Comment: And you assume we know waht a $10 Digital Ocean Droplet does? I do not - I live in my own hardware or Azure. So, tell us what it looks like.

Comment: @TomTom 2gb memory, 1 cpu, 50gb ssd.  Running Ubuntu 16 with a lamp stack.  digitalocean.com/pricing/

Comment: Whow. Not that shabby. A little low on CPU, but should not be a problem.

Comment: Okay well thanks everyone for your help.  I won't keep the thread going here any longer.  Everything is optimized besides the last 2 queries with the datetime index.   If anyone sees how to optimize the last 2 queries, that would be very helpful answer.

Comment: For the first of the last two queries try an index on `eth_address (id, name)`, maybe that helps the `GROUP BY`. For the second of the last two queries, if you're already on MySQL 8.0, which introduced descending indexes, an index on `eth_addresses_tx (from_tx DESC, total_tx DESC)` might help the `GROUP BY` and the `ORDER BY`.

Comment: @cyberkali Additional information request, please. Post on pastebin.com or here.
RAM on your Host server 
complete (not edited) my.cnf-ini 
Text results of: 
A) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; 
B) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
C) complete MySQLTuner.com  report if readily available - 7 or more days uptime is helpful
Optional very helpful information, if available includes -
htop   OR  top for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a linux/unix list of limits, 
iostat -x when system is busy for an idea of IOPS by device, 
for server tuning analysis.

Answer (score 1):

**Hash indexing is bad when table is big**

Assuming `hash` is some form of "hash", `eth_addresses_tx` has a very inefficient `PRIMARY KEY`.  When a table (or index) gets bigger than can be cached in RAM *and* the key is "random" (as are hashes), things slow down because the block needed is less and less likely to be cached in RAM.
What do do?

- Consider using some non-'random' index
- Shrink the data -- Do you need 4-byte INT for the fields?  `eth_addresses` -- 3M rows could be handled by a 3-byte `MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED`.
- `address VARCHAR(42)` -- If that is really `0x` plus 40 hex digits, pack it into `BINARY(20)` (20 bytes) with the help of `LEFT` and `UNHEX`.
- Could from/to_tx be normalized?  Are they hashes, too?
- Do the `DECIMALs` nee to be that big.  `(14,6)` takes 7 bytes; `FLOAT` takes 4 (but has fewer significant digits).  What kind of value is "volume"?  Cubic furlongs?  Stock shares traded?  Books in a trilogy?  Fluid ounces?  If you need exact values, then `DECIMAL` is required.  But is 6 decimal places enough?  (Not for Gwei or Wei.)  `FLOAT`'s 7 significant digits *may* be good enough for summary totals?

**Better indexes**

```
WHERE datetimeTx >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
  AND address_id = $address_id;
```

needs `INDEX(address_id, datetimeTx)` in this order.

```
WHERE  from_tx = $from_tx
ORDER BY  datetimeTx DESC
LIMIT  $limit;
```

very much needs `INDEX(from_tx, datetimeTx)` in this order.  Ditto for `(address_id, datetimeTx)`.  This should eliminate the 'filesort', but more importantly, it will need to look at only 10 rows, not thousands (see your `EXPLAINs`).

This gets trickier:

```
WHERE address_id = $address_id
  AND value > 0
  AND datetimeTx >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), ...)
```

You cannot effectively use two "ranges" in a single index.  The best the optimizer can do is pick between the above index and `INDEX(address_id, value)`.

The query with the `LEFT JOIN` is difficult to improve on because the `WHERE` and the `GROUP BY` reference more than one table.

Can't improve `ORDER BY total_tx DESC, from_tx DESC LIMIT 100` because `total_tx` is an aggregate.  (But, see "Summary tables". below.)

More on indexing:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql

**eth_addresses_tx**

Assuming that is the 'big' table, we should look seriously at its `PRIMARY KEY`.  Assuming `hash` is needed, here is the best thing to do:

```
PRIMARY KEY(address_id, datetimeTx,   -- to make queries efficient
            hash)                     -- to assure uniqueness
UNIQUE(hash)      -- constraint for `hash`
```

The table is "clustered" on the PK.  The queries would be fetching 'consecutive' rows with this PK.  This is much better than the random nature caused by `PK(hash)`.

**Summary Table(s)**

But the real winner would probably be to have a Summary table.  It would get new rows added hourly.  Reports on daily, weekly, etc could be computed from this table.

Summary tables:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables

**Tuning (unlikely)**

If you provide the `GLOBAL STATUS and VARIABLES`, I will look at them.  But you "can't tune your way out of a performance problem".  Especially when there are indexes to be added and/or summary tables to be built.